# Is it possible to use Hot Chocolate execution engine directly, without a web server?

Tags: .net, graphql, hotchocolate

Is it possible to run and call Hot Chocolate execution engine directly, without hosting it as a web server and calling it by HTTP?

I imagine something like this:

```
var query = ... ;// a GraphQl query string
var engine = new HotChocolate.Engine();
engine.Execute(query);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use approach described in [the article about integration tests](https://chillicream.com/blog/2019/04/11/integration-tests).

```cs
    var query = ... ;// a GraphQl query string

    IQueryExecutor executor = Schema.Create(c =>
    {
        c.RegisterQueryType<Query>();
    })
    .MakeExecutable();

    IReadOnlyQueryRequest request =
        QueryRequestBuilder.New()
            .SetQuery(query)
            .Create();

    IExecutionResult result = await executor.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the documentation for the integration testing.